# Bug nas abas "mês" e "interessante"

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Ao acessar a aba [mês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=month) e [interessante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) pela aba:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Notei no rodapé isso:

<kbd>[image: tags]</kbd>

Eu não tenho essas tags cadastradas, vejam o tags ignoradas está vazio:

<kbd>[image: tags ignoradas]</kbd>

Outra coisa se eu clicar no link `"preferencias de tags ignoradas"` da imagem eu sou levado para este link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/26552

Só que é exibido a página 404, isso porque o meu ID não é `26552` e sim `3635`, ou seja está me sendo exibido configurações de outro usuário.

Depois de alguns minutos as abas voltaram ao normal e isso sumiu, pode ser um bug no "cache" do lado servidor creio eu.

Comment: Não consegui simular isso, como faço isso aqui exatamente?

Comment: @Randrade Sim, ele sumiu depois de um tempo, ocorreu primeiro em uma aba, depois sumiu, então fui na outra o mesmo problema apertei f5 varias vezes e continuou, então depois de alguns minutos sozinho voltou ao normal.

Comment: Eu tenho essas tags igonoradas e acessei essas abas agora pouco.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Melhor tipo de bug para sanar. kkkk

Comment: @Murilo por isso penso que é o cache, no caso o cache no back-end foi gerado pelo seu acesso, pois se olhar bem 26552 é o seu ID. É um bug bem louco :D

Comment: O Murilo invadiu o meu perfil D:

Comment: Bom já sabemos como causar o bug. Alguém precisa ter tag igonorada e acessar depois alguém sem acessa.

Comment: Obrigada por reportar, tou investigando.

Comment: @Murilo bug resolvido! Você nunca mais vai hackear o meu perfil hahahaha :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este bug foi resolvido e a correção já está em produção. Como as abas de perguntas por mês/semana/interessantes são bastante acessadas, todo o conteúdo dessas abas é cacheado durante 3 minutos. Para usuários anônimos, por exemplo, essas abas renderizam exatamente as mesmas perguntas, então parece uma otimização razoável. Porém, a chave de cache utilizada não estava levando em conta as tags ignoradas de cada usuário, o que resultava na mesma página sendo cacheada pra todo mundo.

Além de incluir as tags ignoradas na chave, também alteramos o link do rodapé para sempre levar os usuários para a mesma url - no caso, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences. Assim, as abas continuam sendo cacheáveis (essa palavra existe?) e podemos reusar o mesmo HTML para diferentes usuários que, por acaso, tenham o mesmo conjunto de tags ignoradas (ou não tenha nenhuma :) )

<3

Comment: Essa resolução foi "intessante". rla4 muito obrigado mesmo. Parabéns :)